# What does green indicate when "Color Offscreen-Rendered Yellow" is turned on

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am testing the off-screen rendering issue caused by different ways of implementing rounded corners. I have tried using cornerRadius and the mask layer as two ways to achieve rounded corners, and I have enabled the "Color Offscreen-Rendered Yellow" option in Xcode.

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var view1: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        v.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let red = UIView()
        red.backgroundColor = .red
        v.addSubview(red)
        red.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
            make.size.equalToSuperview()
        }
        return v
    }()
    
    lazy var view2: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30),
                                      radius: 30,
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: 2 * Double.pi,
                                      clockwise: true).cgPath
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        v.layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        v.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let red = UIView()
        red.backgroundColor = .red
        v.addSubview(red)
        red.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
            make.size.equalToSuperview()
        }
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)
        
        view1.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(30)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
        }
        view2.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(30)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
        }
    }
}
```

I found that the view with rounded corners set using cornerRadius is highlighted in green.

[image]

I don't understand what this represents and why the off-screen rendering flag is not the usual yellow color.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I see both coloured in yellow.

Comment: @Sweeper Really? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 15.0 and tested on a Simulator running iOS 17.0.

Comment: @Sweeper I also use Xcode15. It seems that the simulator is indeed normal, but I encountered this problem when testing on two real machines.